# When I tried to fetch List, it gives me zero(0) items after fetch

Tags: flutter, dart

When I attempt to populate this list, item Count is 0, but It really shouldn't be.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:trilhaapp/model/post_model.dart';

class PostsRepository {
  Future<List<PostModel>> fetchPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var postList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return (postList as List).map((e) => PostModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}

body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: posts.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    var post = posts[index];
```

Am I fetching wrong?

Comment: Two things required when updating the UI based on a API call. First one is handling the loader while fetching the data so please do show and hide the loader before and after successful api call. And the second one is updating the UI after the assignment is done. So please do use setState method after the assignment of post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FutureBuilder` and change your code like this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<PostModel>>(
  future: PostsRepository().fetchPosts(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    } else {
      List<PostModel> posts = snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: posts.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          var post = posts[index];
          // Build your list item using 'post'
        },
      );
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: but mind that PostRepository and ListView.builder are in different classes. Should I keep returning ListView?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what doyoumean, please update your question with UI and Repository code then I can update my answare basedon it.

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer this for the reference:

In the below code we have handled the two things:

1. Loader for the API call.
2. Data addition and UI Decomposition after the api call.

**1. Loader for the API call:**
This has been handled by using the nullable state at the start named as **postList**.
And in the build method please do observe that a ternary operator has been used to null check the state variable. Which checks the following:
if the postList is null then **CircleProgressIndicator** will be shown. if the state is non-nullable then the UI will be started to get drawn.

**2. Data addition and UI Decomposition after the api call.**

Please do observe the following methods for understanding the API calls:

- ***initState***
- ***postApiGetMethod***

The main function of data loading and the setState method is handled in the ***postApiGetMethod***. Where the API is called and then the value from the api is decoded and it has been assigned to the state. And then the setState method is called ad the data is successfully loaded to the state.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PostApiFetchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostApiFetchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PostApiFetchScreen> createState() => _PostApiFetchScreenState();
}

class _PostApiFetchScreenState extends State<PostApiFetchScreen> {
// NOTE - variable for holding the API Route
  final String _postApiFetchUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
// NOTE - State for the data to draw the widget
  var postList = null;

// NOTE - method for handling the API call and data assignment
  void postApiGetMethod() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(_postApiFetchUrl),
    );
// NOTE - Check for the successful data fetch
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('Response data is ${responseBody.length}');
// NOTE - Data Assignment
      postList = responseBody;
// NOTE - setState for rebuilding the UI
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    postApiGetMethod();
  }
// NOTE - Widget of the overall post container
  Widget postContainer({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required int id,
  }) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Divider(
          height: 2,
        ),
        postInfoTile(
          key: 'ID',
          pair: id.toString(),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        postInfoTile(
          key: 'Title',
          pair: title,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        postInfoTile(
          key: 'Body',
          pair: body,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 3,
        ),
        const Divider(
          height: 2,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

// NOTE - Widget for the post data holder
  Widget postInfoTile({
    required String key,
    required String pair,
  }) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          '$key:',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 20),
        Expanded(child: Text(pair)),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Post API Consume',
        ),
      ),
// NOTE - handling the loader
      body: postList != null
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: postList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => postContainer(
                body: postList[index]['body'],
                title: postList[index]['title'],
                id: postList[index]['id'],
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. Please explain what this code does and how exactly it answers the question. Doing so allows the OP and anyone else who may find your answer to know precisely what caused the problem in the first place so they can avoid it or know how to fix it in the future. In its current state, your answer teaches the OP nothing beyond how to copy and paste code from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for the feedback. Will update the comment and explanation for the code.